# Java: Can not read data file in JUnit test

Tags: java, junit

my test package looks like

```
test/
    java/
        com/
           algos/
                graphs/
                      GraphTest.java
    resources/
             graphs/
                   tinyG.txt
```

The `GraphTest` tried to read `tinyG` as follows

```
@Test
public void testTinyG() throws IOException {
    final Graph g = new Graph(getBufferedReaderFor("tinyG.txt"));
    System.out.println(g.toString());
}

private static BufferedReader getBufferedReaderFor(final String filename) {
    return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(GraphTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/graphs/" + filename)));
}
```

It fails with `NullPointerException` as

```
GraphTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/graphs/" + filename)
```

returns `null`.

What is that I am doing wrong here?

`tinyG` has data like

```
13
13
0 5
4 3
0 1
9 12
6 4
5 4
0 2
```

Thank you

Comment: GraphTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/graphs/" + filename)., When your location is from /resources/graphs, why are you giving path from /graphs only?

Please let us know, if /resources is at same level as that of /test or even down under test? Then you need to include parent path as well.

Comment: What do you get when you print out the current working directory?

Answer (score 2):

When Eclipse runs JUnit tests for a project, it normally starts the tests using the working directory of the project. So, to access tinyG.txt from the classpath, you would have to use the path `/test/resources/graphs/tinyG.txt`.  The only way to have `tinyG.txt` work would for it to reside in the same directory as the .class file.